# Cordova InAppBrowser with _blank option stops me using microphone even after providing necessary permissions on Android

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I am using cordova inAppBrowser plugin on Android application to load the webview which has voice recognition feature.

If I use `_self` option then the microphone works, But if i use `_blank` option then the microphone doesn't respond.

This is how I am trying to invoke the webview.

```
let target = "_blank";
let options = "location=no,clearcache=yes";

cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
```

I have provided RecordAudio & ModifyAudioSettings permissions but still it doesn't work. Please help.